# Really weird keystroke issue with Shell32 and pyautogui. Keystrokes not sending

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, keystroke, pyautogui

I am having a frustrating and weird problem with sending keystrokes. Few things to clarify first. The application doesn't have any anti-cheat and the sending keystrokes works under windows XP on virtual machine, but not on my main machine under windows 10.
Using simple code as

```
pyautogui.typewrite("4") or
pyautogui.KeyDown("4") or
pyautogui.press("4") or
Shell.sendkey("4")
```

simply won't send the key to the application I am trying on, but it will send it everywhere else:browser,notepad you name it.
Please help as I am stuck.....

Comment: better **in question** write name of this program . Maybe It uses some non standard method to get keys.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "name of the program"? 
In the cases above I am using either import pyautogui or import win32.client

Comment: I mean application which makes problem. application which doesn't receive keys.